# SIGXCPU error in C program

Tags: c, recursion, infinite-loop

The following program is not producing output.  It enters the for loop and takes one value (via `scanf`) but after that the code block stops execution. Ideone (an online compiler and debugging tool) says that SIGXCPU signal is generated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long fact(int);
int z(int);

int main()
{
    int i, n; 
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    int a[10];long b[10];
    int c[10];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        b[i]=fact(a[i]);
        c[i]=z(b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", c[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

long fact(int m)
{
    if (m==1) return 1;
    else return (m*fact(m-1));
}

int z (int s)
{
    int c=0, temp;
    temp=s%10;
    if(temp!=0) return c;
    else
    {
        c++; z(temp);
    }
}
```

What does the SIGXCPU signal mean?

Comment: Ideone is an online compiler and debugging tool. Your program is using Ideone which is also used by other users. Your code would have exceeded its limit on consumed processor time.

Comment: This is a message that you don't normally get in your own system, but Ideone has set a limit in place to set an upper bound to how many CPU cycles per program are allowed. Search for RLIMIT_CPU to see how one can set these limits for themselves.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `SIGXCPU` signal is sent each second to a process after it exceeds its limit on consumed processor time ([`RLIMIT_CPU`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrlimit.html)), or, for realtime processes, its limit on running without sleeping. 
The problem here is with your recursive `z` function that does not stop and calls itself again and again (and causes a stack overflow). Fix its stop condition.

From the [signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html) man page:

> ```
> Signal | Default Action | Description
> -------+----------------+-------------------------
> SIGXCPU| A              | CPU time limit exceeded.
> ```
>
> The default actions are as follows:
>
> **A** - Abnormal termination of the process.
>     Additionally, implementation-defined abnormal termination actions,
>   such as creation of a core file, may occur.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably consuming more CPU time and/or related resources than ideone will allow so your program doesn't overload the site.

Check your recursion and termination conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you find that no problem in recursion, then you can change the CPU time limit(RLIMIT_CPU) using:

```
setrlimit(); (set time slice for cpu)
```

In this program, we set cpu time to that process equal to 15 seconds. You can set as per requirement, but make sure it's low as soon as possible because your cpu are busy long time to executing that process and we loss the multitasking and concerancy of cpu.

```
struct rlimit v;

v.rlim_cur=15;           //set the soft limit to 15 sec

setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU,&v);
```

All done after that you set time slice to cpu 15 seconds.

Hope you understand.